# Questions regarding sorting, saving value of clicks etc

Tags: sorting, dynamic, filter, rank

As I didn't find anything that specifically answers my questions, I hope I find some answers here. I want to design a little tool for my friends (like a clicker game tool) where you can click on the circle and it will count the amount of clicks. However, only the relative amount should be shown (in percentage) and it should be possible to search for all entries (rank 1-11). Moreover, the top 3 should always be on top.

Example of a "prototype": https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWB4I.jpg

[image]

What approach would you recommend in trying to realize this small project? Is HTML/CSS/JS the right way? How do I store the "score" in a DB? Switch to PHP/MySQL? I know it's a lot of questions, but any guidance is helpful.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you care about cheating? If yes, you need a centralized data storage. If not, you might as well use the fancy JS shit (sorry for the language).

Comment: So would it be possible to store data by clicks (if they click themselves) in a mysql db and show the relative distribution (rank) on the front-end? Is it possible with HTML or PHP only?